# How do I use case condition with aggregate?

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have two columns in my table:

```
  col1                  count
   a                      5
   b                      10
   c                      15
   az                     10
```

I want to change the value az to a and then sum count, so, result would be:

TABLE=

```
  col1                 count
   a                    15
   b                    10
   c                    15
```

How do I do this in SQL?

I did:

```
   select col1, SUM(count)
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE
   WHERE TABLE.col1 = CASE WHEN TABLE.col1 = 'az' THEN 'a' ELSE TABLE.col1 END GROUP BY fodc.country
```

But, it does not give the right results. It gives the unexpected results and completely eliminates `az`

How to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `case` in the `select`:

```
select (case when col1 = 'az' then 'a' else col1 end),
       sum(count)
from table1
group by 1;
```

Comment: I am getting true, false as values in col1, when I do this.

Comment: sorry, I was doing `(col1 = case when col1 = 'az' then 'a' else col1 end)` and for some reason that does not work and what you posted works.